# What kind of datestyle can this be?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have a table with a column defined as:

```
"timestamp" int8 NULL,
```

which stores values like
'1638462043745210034'
When I try to cast it to timestamp or timestamp with time-zone

```
SELECT '1638462043745210034'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' ;
```

it returns an error:

> date/time field value out of range: "1638462043745210034"   Hint:
> Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

What kind of datestyle can it be and how can it be converted to a normal timestamp?

Comment: Looks like the dreaded [unix epoch](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like nanoseconds since the epoch:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1638462043745210034 / 1000000000.0);

         to_timestamp         
══════════════════════════════
 2021-12-02 17:20:43.74521+01
(1 row)
```