# Group by day from nanosecond timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, epoch

I have a table column `transaction_timestamp` storing timestamps as epochs with ***nanosecond*** resolution.

How do I group and/or count by day? I guess I have to convert the nanosecond timestamp to milliseconds first. How can I do that?

I tried:

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', CAST((transaction_timestamp /pow(10,6))as bigint)), COUNT(*)
FROM transaction
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', transaction_timestamp)
```

which is does not work:

```
error: function date_trunc(unknown, bigint) does not exist
```

I also tried this:

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', to_timestamp(transaction_timestamp / 1000000000.0)),
 COUNT(*)
FROM transaction
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', transaction_timestamp)
```

Comment: You seem to be dividing a timestamp by dome function and casting that to an integer, then trying to treat that as if it is a timestamp?  Why not just truncate the timestamp?

Comment: it could work I guess, how to write that ? I'm weak at psql

Comment: See the answer here [Nanosecond timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71438725/what-kind-of-datestyle-can-this-be)

Comment: how should I use it ? see what I tried in edited question please

Comment: I try to group/count by day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic conversion as instructed here:

- [What kind of datestyle can this be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71438725/what-kind-of-datestyle-can-this-be/71439037#71439037)

Repeat the same expression in `GROUP BY`, or use a simple positional reference, like:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(transaction_timestamp / 1000000000.0))
     , count(*)
FROM   transaction
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Be aware that [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) assumes **UTC** time zone for the given epoch to produce a **`timestamp with time zone`** (`timestamptz`). The following `date_trunc()` then uses the `timezone` setting of your current session to determine where to truncate "days". You may want to define a certain time zone explicitly ...
Basics:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Typically, it's best to work with a proper `timestamptz` to begin with. Unfortunately, Postgres timestamps only offer microsecond resolution. Since you need nanoseconds, your approach seems justified.